# Mudar estrutura de matriz

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, design-pattern, estrutura-de-dados

Como mudar a estrutura de uma matriz? Pode ser utilizando excel ou via programação. Já fiz minha solução com Java mas ficou uma gambiarra danada :). Além disso não está genérico o suficiente.

Existe algum design pattern, ou conceito de estrutura de dados que resolva isso? O objetivo final e poder ordenar a tabela por data, o que não é possível com a tabela no formato inicial.

[image: tabelas]

Comment: Poderia definir melhor sua dúvida, sua pergunta está um pouco ampla

Comment: A tabela 1 representa uma atividade que acontece numa determinada data e local, preciso rearranjar o conteúdo da tabela 1, no formato da tabela 2, para que possa visualizar as atividades ordenadas por data. A solução pode ser utilizando alguma linguagem de programção ou o excel. Consegui explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1):

Vamos criar primeiro uma classe `Tabela`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.function.Function;

class Tabela<L, C, X> {
    private final Set<C> colunas;
    private final Set<L> linhas;
    private final Map<L, Map<C, X>> celulas;
    private final Function<? super L, String> strLinhas;
    private final Function<? super C, String> strColunas;
    private final Function<? super X, String> strCelulas;

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface TabelaConsumer<L, C, X> {
        public void accept(L linha, C coluna, X celula);
    }

    public Tabela(
            Collection<L> linhas,
            Collection<C> colunas,
            Function<? super L, String> strLinhas,
            Function<? super C, String> strColunas,
            Function<? super X, String> strCelulas)
    {
        this.colunas = new LinkedHashSet<>(colunas);
        this.linhas = new LinkedHashSet<>(linhas);
        this.strLinhas = strLinhas;
        this.strColunas = strColunas;
        this.strCelulas = strCelulas;
        this.celulas = new LinkedHashMap<>(this.linhas.size());
        for (L linha : this.linhas) {
            Map<C, X> valoresLinha = new LinkedHashMap<>(this.colunas.size());
            for (C coluna : this.colunas) {
                valoresLinha.put(coluna, null);
            }
            this.celulas.put(linha, valoresLinha);
        }
    }

    public void put(L linha, C coluna, X valor) {
        if (!linhas.contains(linha) || !colunas.contains(coluna)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        celulas.get(linha).put(coluna, valor);
    }

    public X get(L linha, C coluna) {
        if (!linhas.contains(linha) || !colunas.contains(coluna)) return null;
        return celulas.get(linha).get(coluna);
    }

    public void forEach(TabelaConsumer<? super L, ? super C, ? super X> consumer) {
        for (L linha : linhas) {
            for (C coluna : colunas) {
                consumer.accept(linha, coluna, get(linha, coluna));
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Integer> calcularLargura() {
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(colunas.size() + 1);

        int m = 0;
        for (L linha : linhas) {
            int x = strLinhas.apply(linha).length();
            if (x > m) m = x;
        }
        lista.add(m);

        for (C coluna : colunas) {
            int n = strColunas.apply(coluna).length();
            for (L linha : linhas) {
                X celula = get(linha, coluna);
                int x = celula == null ? 0 : strCelulas.apply(celula).length();
                if (x > n) n = x;
            }
            lista.add(n);
        }

        return lista;
    }

    private void imprimirSeparador(StringBuilder sb, int tamanho) {
        sb.append("+-");
        for (int i = 0; i <= tamanho; i++) {
            sb.append('-');
        }
    }

    private void imprimirSeparador(StringBuilder sb, List<Integer> tamanhos) {
        for (int i : tamanhos) {
            imprimirSeparador(sb, i);
        }
        sb.append("+\n");
    }

    private void imprimirCelula(StringBuilder sb, int tamanho, String conteudo) {
        sb.append("| ").append(conteudo);
        for (int i = conteudo.length(); i <= tamanho; i++) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
    }

    private void imprimirCabecalho(StringBuilder sb, List<Integer> tamanhos) {
        Iterator<Integer> it = tamanhos.iterator();
        imprimirCelula(sb, it.next(), "");
        for (C coluna : colunas) {
            imprimirCelula(sb, it.next(), strColunas.apply(coluna));
        }
        sb.append("|\n");
    }

    private void imprimirLinha(StringBuilder sb, List<Integer> tamanhos, L linha) {
        Iterator<Integer> it = tamanhos.iterator();
        imprimirCelula(sb, it.next(), strLinhas.apply(linha));
        for (C coluna : colunas) {
            X celula = get(linha, coluna);
            imprimirCelula(sb, it.next(), celula == null ? "" : strCelulas.apply(celula));
        }
        sb.append("|\n");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        List<Integer> tamanhos = calcularLargura();
        int larguraTotal = tamanhos.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum) + 3 * tamanhos.size() + 2;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(larguraTotal * (linhas.size() * 2 + 3));
        imprimirSeparador(sb, tamanhos);
        imprimirCabecalho(sb, tamanhos);
        imprimirSeparador(sb, tamanhos);
        for (L linha : linhas) {
            imprimirLinha(sb, tamanhos, linha);
            imprimirSeparador(sb, tamanhos);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Esta classe é genérica. Tendo ela, então vamos utilizar para os seus dados as classes `Local` e `Atividade` a definirmos, bem como a classe `java.time.LocalDate` para o conteúdo da tabela:

```
class Local {
    private final String nome;

    public Local(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }
}

class Atividade {
    private final String nome;

    public Atividade(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Por fim, o código que usa tudo isso, criando a tabela 1 e transformando-a na tabela 2:

```
class Teste {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FMT = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Define os locais e atividades.
        Local casa = new Local("Casa");
        Local escola = new Local("Escola");
        Local trabalho = new Local("Trabalho");
        Atividade estudo = new Atividade("Estudo");
        Atividade treino = new Atividade("Treino");
        Atividade apresentacao = new Atividade("Apresentação");

        // Define a estrutura da tabela 1.
        Tabela<Atividade, Local, LocalDate> tabela1 = new Tabela<>(
                Arrays.asList(estudo, treino, apresentacao),
                Arrays.asList(casa, escola, trabalho),
                Object::toString,
                Object::toString,
                ld -> ld.format(FMT)
        );

        // Preenche a tabela 1.
        tabela1.put(estudo, casa, LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 1));
        tabela1.put(estudo, escola, LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 10));
        tabela1.put(estudo, trabalho, LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1));
        tabela1.put(treino, casa, LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 3));
        tabela1.put(treino, escola, LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 4));
        tabela1.put(treino, trabalho, LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 1));
        tabela1.put(apresentacao, casa, LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 2));
        tabela1.put(apresentacao, escola, LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 3));
        tabela1.put(apresentacao, trabalho, LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 10));

        // Mostra a tabela 1.
        System.out.println("Tabela 1:");
        System.out.println(tabela1);

        // Descobre as datas que são linhas da tabela 2.
        Set<LocalDate> datas = new TreeSet<>();
        tabela1.forEach((atividade, local, data) -> datas.add(data));

        // Define a estrutura da tabela 2.
        Tabela<LocalDate, Atividade, Local> tabela2 = new Tabela<>(
                datas,
                Arrays.asList(estudo, treino, apresentacao),
                ld -> ld.format(FMT),
                Object::toString,
                Object::toString
        );

        // Preenche a tabela 2 com base nos dados da tabela 1.
        tabela1.forEach((atividade, local, data) -> tabela2.put(data, atividade, local));

        // Mostra a tabela 2.
        System.out.println("Tabela 2:");
        System.out.println(tabela2);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
Tabela 1:
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
|              | Casa       | Escola     | Trabalho   |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Estudo       | 01/02/2017 | 10/03/2017 | 01/01/2017 |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Treino       | 03/05/2017 | 04/02/2017 | 01/05/2017 |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Apresentação | 02/02/2017 | 03/03/2017 | 10/12/2017 |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+

Tabela 2:
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
|            | Estudo   | Treino   | Apresentação |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 01/01/2017 | Trabalho |          |              |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 01/02/2017 | Casa     |          |              |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 02/02/2017 |          |          | Casa         |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 04/02/2017 |          | Escola   |              |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 03/03/2017 |          |          | Escola       |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 10/03/2017 | Escola   |          |              |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 01/05/2017 |          | Trabalho |              |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 03/05/2017 |          | Casa     |              |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 10/12/2017 |          |          | Trabalho     |
+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

[**Veja funcionando aqui no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/ytvtN2)

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, vou analisar pra entender esse código  mais tarde.